# Overcoming web authentication with android studio

Tags: php, json, android-studio

[image]
I have a server that gives JSON data to my android application. How to overcome the authentication code for username and password in android studio when the web uses authentication like this? Whereas I want people who use my mobile application do not need to type their username and password

Answer (score 0):

If the user's username and password is available within the android application, you will be able to append them in the url in this format `http://username:password@example.com/`. Reference: https://serverfault.com/questions/371907/can-you-pass-user-pass-for-http-basic-authentication-in-url-parameters

Comment: I"m assuming you are making an api call to some server. You can add the username and password to the api url.

Comment: Where i typed its code in api?
i send code conection to JSON here

https://i.stack.imgur.com/QcRFH.png